# visibility:visible/hidden div

Tags: jquery, css, html, visibility

What is the best way to show a div when clicked on a button and then hide it with a close button??

My Jquery code is as follows:

```
$(".imageIcon").click(function(){
$('.imageShowWrapper').css("visibility", 'visible');
});
 $(".imageShowWrapper").click(function(){
$('.imageShowWrapper').css("visibility", 'hidden');
});
```

except the problem I'm having is it closes automatically without any clicks. It loads everything ok, displays for about 1/2 sec and then closes. Any ideas?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can use the `show` and `hide` methods:

```
$(".imageIcon").click(function() {
    $('.imageShowWrapper').show();
});

$(".imageShowWrapper").click(function() {
    $(this).hide();
});
```

Comment: hey thanks for your reply, I want the div to be hidden first, would i need use the same function hide() or can i just use the CSS visibilty property

Comment: @Scott Robertson, you are welcome, you can hide the div outside of event handler, hide sets `display:none` to an element.

Comment: hmm maybe I didn't implement it properly I'm still learning alot of this stuff. In my CSS file i placed `display:none` in the properties of imageShowWrapper but now the Jquery wont affect the div

Comment: There is obviously something more to my script stopping this from working, Thanks for all replies

Answer (score 5):

According to your requirement, I believe what you need is as simple as this: http://jsfiddle.net/linmic/6Yadu/

However, using the visibility is different from using show/hide function, gory details: [What is the difference between visibility:hidden and display:none?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133051/what-is-the-difference-between-visibilityhidden-and-displaynone)

Comment: this is exatcly what I want and is pretty much what my original code is, its just doesn't work for some reason.Thanks for reply

Answer (score 2):

Another option:

```
$(".imageIcon, .imageShowWrapper").click(function() {  
    $(".imageShowWrapper").toggle($(this).hasClass('imageIcon'));     
});
```

You can also use `fadeToggle` and `slideToggle`

Answer (score 0):

You would get a smoother transition using the fade methods:

```
var imageIcon = $(".imageIcon"),
    imageShowWrapper = $(".imageShowWrapper");

imageIcon.on("click", function(){
  imageShowWrapper.stop().fadeIn();
});

imageShowWrapper.on("click", function(){
   $(this).stop().fadeOut();
});
```

Demo: http://jsbin.com/uhapom/edit#javascript,html,live

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".imageIcon, .imageShowWrapper").click(function(){
    $('.imageShowWrapper').toggle();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Tough to say without seeing your html and jquery part of the code. But, looks like the part where you show/hide the div is getting affected by page reload ? You might be placing the code that shows/hide div inside a`$(document).ready(function() { .....})` block. Also, another related point  to note would be that whenever html elements like button, anchor etc is clicked, the click is considered to be of default type = submit, and the page will reload under this situation too.To stop that, one could use `event.preventDefault()`